# How to prevent a wrong uuid with model injection binding?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Using Laravel 6, I inject a model in a controller like this :

```
public function edit(School $school)
{
    return view('/school/form', ['school' => $school]);
}
```

All is working fine when I enter an url like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/schools/3d537a0f-4c74-4fae-99af-6f1b2c4b34c8/edit
```

But if I try another url like this one (with a wrong uuid):

```
http://localhost:8000/schools/3d537a0f-4c74-4fae-99af-6f/edit
```

Then I have this PostgreSQL error :

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid
> input syntax for type uuid: "3d537a0f-4c74-4fae-99af-6f1b2c4b34c"
> (SQL: select * from "schools" where "id" =
> 3d537a0f-4c74-4fae-99af-6f1b2c4b34c limit 1)

Does it mean that I have to check the uuid before ? Is there any elegant way to prevent this and to have an automatic redirection to a 404 page ?

Comment: Did you look at this? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24703

Comment: Thanks for this link. I think my model is well configured : public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string'; So I think the problem is not the model.

Comment: I refer to the solution of the issue: *I deleted the session cache file inside storage/framework/sessions and then all back to work.* I would suggest to clear the cache entirely though

Comment: I tried to clear the cache, without success. i continue to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your route definition, you can use a constraint on the parameter to avoid matching:

```
Route::get('school/{school}/edit', 'SchoolController@edit')
    ->where('school', '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$');
```

This will result in a 404 because the route doesn't match invalid UUIDs. More info about this topic can be found [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints). There is also an explanation how to define a global constraint to avoid repeating it for every route.

---

For resource routes, the solution is slightly different. You will need to define a global constraint in the `boot()` method of your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::pattern('school', '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$');
```

In case your resource is called differently than your route parameter, you need to customize the parameter name when defining the route resource:

```
Route::resource('university', 'UniversityController', [
    'parameters' => ['university' => 'school']
]);
```

*Note: this is just for illustration, I doubt you need it...*

Comment: Hi Namoshek. I tried your solution , but I use ressources route like this : Route::resources([
        'schools' => 'SchoolController',
    ])->where('school', '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$'); And it does not work . Perhaps I must write individual routes ?

Comment: @Dom I added a solution for route resources.

Comment: Hi. it works like that. Thanks. But it seems a little complicated. Perhaps another solution could be to use a string and not an uuid for the id of the table, even if it is an uuid stored in this column ? What do you think about that ? Dom

Comment: If you use something different than the primary key as route parameter, you will need to use the solution provided by @cbaconnier. And as it isn't really more concise... it doesn't really matter. ;)

Comment: Laravel returns a html 404 when you use pattern and pass in a different datatype. Is there a simple way to return json akin to using ->missing() when the route model isn't found?

Comment: @FiHoran I think declaring the same route a second time without the constraint, but definitely _after_ the one with the constraint, could be one solution to this problem. If you want to handle all requests within the same action, you can do that as well, but then the route constraint doesn't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

yes, please check if id exits then return data else redirect to 404.

Or you can use Eloquent findOrFail method.Example:

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);
```

this will redirect to 404 automatically if record not found.

Comment: Hi ashish bansal. thanks for your reply. Yes it would work like you write. But with this method I have to forget the "model injection". And I like this method (because it allows to have a controller very short...). And more : I think (but to try) that findOrFail('wrong uuid') will return the same postgre error.

Comment: IRC model binding does uses `findOrFail()` which will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` on unsuccessful result when debug is enabled. Disabled Laravel will catch that exception to render a customizable page for it. I think the problem in unrelated. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an issue somewhere else that interfere somehow with the model resolution and should look deeper what the cause (like a package perhaps?).

As a workaround you can use explicit binding to prevent this error

In your **RouteServiceProvider.php** file

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

...

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('school', function ($value) {
        if (! Uuid::isValid($value)) { 
            throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(School::class, $value);
        }

        return School::findOrFail($value);
    });
}
```

But, **this is a hack** only to **patch** an error that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Your solution isn't as bad as you describe. The internal logic when using `Route::pattern()` is somewhat similar. As soon as you have access to the `'school'` parameter, you can also just add a global constraint. It will throw a 404 instead of a `ModelNotFoundException` though.

Comment: What I did is to mimic the behavior when the laravel "sucessfully" fail to find the model. In my opinon this kind of patch should be done only if we can't fix the root problem. It could be a bug introduced with laravel 6 with postgresql though

Comment: Nope, it's just that you cannot add a local route binding constraint when using route resources. You can still use a global constraint as shown in my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't need a constraint either. Laravel returns  `ModelNotFoundException` *(which is a 404 btw)*, with a valid or invalid UUID since the Model with the `['uuid' => 'MY-INVALID-UUID']` does not exists.

Comment: Normally yes, but according to the question the postgresql server cannot handle strings which are invalid UUIDs. Maybe the framework shouldn't even allow such database calls, but the simpliest solution is to just don't route calls with invalid UUIDs (which is also a good thing from a security perspective).